# What is the best inversion of control container to use when developing on ASP .NET MVC 3 with EF?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I am developing an enterprise web application and have a little knowledge for inversion of control containers available today. I have an average knowledge for ASP .NET MVC 3. Among the choices I have are Castle.Windsor and Unity. Both has inversion of control container but I don't have the knowledge of which is the best for a ASP .NET MVC 3 web application also that is using an Entity Framework 4.1. Do you know what would I pick as the best or do you know what would be compatible for a web app I am using to develop? Thank you in advance.

Comment: They're all much of a muchness. A lot of it is personal preference as they all perform the same function. There are some good benchmarks here: http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/05/ioc-container-benchmark-rerevisted.html

Comment: Here's a more complete set of figures. After reading this and further research I went with SimpleInjector. It's very good. http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as best container. If there was others wouldn't probably existed because everyone would have used this best container. As long as you are using Inversion of Control properly it doesn't really matter which container you choose. Unity, Ninject, Castle Windsor, StructureMap, ... all have a custom DependencyResolver for ASP.NET MVC which could be used to inject dependencies into objects.

If speed and performance is the only thing you care about then you may take a look at [`Funq`](http://funq.codeplex.com/), the container used by [`ServiceStack`](http://www.servicestack.net/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the information Darin. I have a clearer decision right now.